# SQL Update Statement Not Updating, No Errors When Executing

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following two update statements scheduled daily to update a column (x_shippit_volumetric_weight) with whichever is greater - net weight or volumetric weight. 
*I have the AND statements in there to stop it overwriting any existing data if it is already present and correct.*

The problem is, the data is not being updated, even when x_shippit_volumetric_weight = 0? Also no errors are shown when executing these two update statements.

Any help on why it's not updating the data would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE stock_items 
SET    x_shippit_volumetric_weight = Round( ( stock_items.x_height * stock_items.x_width_cm * stock_items.x_length_cm ) / 4000, 4) 
WHERE Round( ( stock_items.x_height * stock_items.x_width_cm * stock_items.x_length_cm ) / 4000, 4) > stock_items.weight
AND x_shippit_volumetric_weight <> Round( ( stock_items.x_height * stock_items.x_width_cm * stock_items.x_length_cm ) / 4000, 4) 
AND (stock_items.x_height * stock_items.x_width_cm * stock_items.x_length_cm) <> 0; 


UPDATE stock_items 
SET    stock_items.x_shippit_volumetric_weight = Round(( stock_items.weight ), 4) 
WHERE  stock_items.weight > Round( ( stock_items.x_height * stock_items.x_width_cm * stock_items.x_length_cm ) / 4000, 4) 
AND stock_items.x_shippit_volumetric_weight <> Round(( stock_items.weight ), 4);
```

Comment: You try to convert the UPDATE statement into SELECT statement to check whether there has any row return? if no row return means you WHERE clause doesn't match any result, so no row was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've discovered the cause of the data not updating (in some cases).
Wherever x_shippit_volumetric_weight has a NULL value, it was not updating. I don't actually understand why, however adding the following UPDATE statements before the other two UPDATE statements alleviates the issue.

```
UPDATE stock_items 
SET    x_shippit_volumetric_weight = 0 
WHERE  x_shippit_volumetric_weight IS NULL;
```